# Visual Studio Code - pregunta sobre HTML

Tags: html, vscode

Buenas las tengan caballeros soy un novato con la tecnología html y me surgió una duda y es que al crear un index, la extensión no puede ser html, porque el IDE la entiende como un archivo Django, en cambio si la extensión es htm si la entiende como un archivo HTML entonces mi pregunta es ¿podría dejarlo de ese modo ó alguien podría hacer el favor de explicarme como solucionarlo?

Comment: Será que tienes instalada una extensión que reconoce los archivos .HTML así?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en configuración se puede cambiar el modo de lenguaje, no sé esa parte. Pero puedes cambiarlo dando click en la esquina inferior derecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También puedes presionar `F1` y escribir "modo lenguaje" y cambiar por defecto cual quieres que interprete el código para resaltarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Alfredo muchas gracias me sirvio